# Python Tic Tac Toe code propblems

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried creating a tic tac toe game using Python but it is not working. Can someone please take a look at it and tell me if I made a mistake?

When I run the game it only prints the board and then asks for a number for x. Once I type that, the game prints a board and closes.

```
def tic_tac_toe(): 

   end = False 
   win_combinations = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6))
   board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
   def draw():
      print(board[0], board[1], board[2]) 
      print(board[3], board[4], board[5])
      print(board[6], board[7], board[8])
      print()
   def player_option_check():
      while True:
        try:
            arg1 = input("please enter number")
            arg1 = int(arg1)
            if arg1 in range(0,9):
                return arg1 - 1
            else:
                print ('not a number on he board')
        except:
            print('this is not a number re try')

   def player_X():

     choice = player_option_check()
     board[choice] = 'x'

   def player_y():

     choice = player_option_check()
     board[choice] = 'y'

   def check_winner_x ():
     for a in win_combinations:
         if board[a[0]] == board[a[1]] == board[a[2]] == 'o':
             print('player o wins')
             return True 
         if board[a[0]] == board[a[1]] == board[a[2]] == 'x':
             print('player x wins')
             return True 
     for a in range(9):
        if board[a] == "X" or board[a] == "O":
             count += 1
     if count == 9:
        print("The game ends in a Tie\n")
        return True
while not end:
    draw()
    end = check_winner_x
    if end == True:
        break
    else:
        player_X()
        draw()
        end = check_winner_x
        if end == True:
            break
        else:
            player_y()
            draw()
        if end==True:
            again_play=print(input("would u like to play again press (y/n)"))
            again_play == "y"
            tic_tac_toe()
        else:
            print('thanks for playing')
            break
tic_tac_toe()
```

So can you please help me find the mistake in my code. This is in Python 3.

Comment: I am afraid, SO is not a free debugging service. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially #1: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: I suggest you add some more `print()` statements to help you identify where the code is not doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's cause you're not calling `check_winner_x`, just assigning it to the value `end` (maybe `print(end)` at the end of the loop to see it's value).

That means that when you get back to the `while` statement, `end` will register as ["truthy"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/1112586) as it's no longer set to `false` and the loop will exit.

Try actually calling `check_winner_x`:

```
end = check_winner_x()
```

Not sure about anything else that might be buggy, but that's definitely a start.